# add modified data to wiki pages

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wiki

I am trying to add the last modified by, and modified date to any wiki pages that are created. I would like these to be added automatically and can not seem to find a way of doing this.

I am running sharepoint foundation 2010.

Any help or guidance is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to add it.

I'd probably use a [Delegate control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478826.aspx) to insert my own control into the PublishingConsole (if that's an OK placement) and then check if the current File is a wikipage and if so display the infomation

Comment: Thanks at least I can stop looking for ways to do it now.  I will look at that moving forward when the need becomes more pressing.